# Is it appropriate to use "pre-covid" in a formal situation when talking about COVID-19?

Tags: idioms

I found [people use "pre-covid"](https://www.google.com/search?bih=559&biw=1097&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03ds-0KtZWo5RUv_XKAZrT74eJlkQ%3A1585618093898&ei=rZyCXt64Ntqo-QbhpbzwBg&q=%22pre-covid%22&oq=%22pre-covid%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJzoFCAAQxAI6BggAEAgQHjoHCCMQsQIQJzoGCAAQBxAeUKYVWIckYJQmaABwAHgAgAG7AYgB2QeSAQMwLjaYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiew_HZx8PoAhVaVN4KHeESD24Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) to refer to the days before COVID-19 spreads.

Of course, it makes sense. The question is whether it is appropriate to use the term in a formal situation, something like business meeting. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of formal context are you talking about here?

Comment: @Fivesideddice Something like business meeting.

Answer (score 2):

Your context is important. If you are engaged in an online discussion or email exchange, I think it is fine to say "pre-covid". In a formal situation, such as an academic paper, you could say something like, "Before the outbreak of the COVID-19 pandemic..."

Comment: Academic papers use coined phrases all the time. You'd want to introduce it first with something like you suggested, but repeatedly using "pre-covid" thereafter would raise no eyebrows.